# strongswan in aws EC2 in VPC1 to AWS site to site vpn in VPC2 - tunnel working but can't ping

Tags: vpn, vpc, strongswan

I have been trying to get strongswan tunnel working from one AWS VPC to another VPC where site-to-site(s2s) VPN is configured for the last two days and the ping doesn't work. No connectivity at all between the instances in two VPC's. The runnel is up and strongswan log says it sent packets to the outside public IP of the s2s VPN and it receives as well. But ping from EC2 in VPC1 to EC2 in VPC2 doesn't work. My setup is below.

**VPC1(call it as AWS VPC)**

Created private subnet 10.10.1.0/24 and no public subnet in this.
Created s2s VPN setup.
Created virtual gateway(VGW) and attached to VPC1.
Created customer gateway with the public IP of the EC2 instance that is running with strongswan in VPC2.
Added static route to the s2s VPN connection as the private subnet(10.20.0.0/24) of VPC2. VGW propagates this route to the VPC1 route table with destination as VGW
Associate VPC1 private subnet to VPC route table
Created an EC2 in the VPC1(**vpc server**) private subnet with IP 10.10.1.140
Security group allows all traffic inbound and out bound

**VPC2(call it as on-premise) in Another AWS account**

Created public subnet 10.20.1.0/24 and a private subnet 10.20.2.0/24
Create an EC2 with IP 10.20.1.73 and an Elastic IP - 52.x.x.x
Install strongswan in it.
Added net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 in /etc/sysctl.conf of strongswan EC2 and run sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
Security group allows all traffic inbound and out bound of VPC2
Created another EC2 instance(**on-premise server**) in the private subnet with IP 10.20.2.132
Updated the private route table to add all traffic to 10.10.1.0/24 to forward to ENI of the strongswan EC2

strongswan config

```
$ cat /etc/strongswan/ipsec.conf
config setup
    uniqueids = no

conn Tunnel1
    auto=start
    left=%defaultroute
    leftid=52.x.x.x (Elastic IP of my strongswan EC2)
    right=52.y.y.y (Outside IP address of my s2s VPN Tunnel1)
    type=tunnel
    leftauth=psk
    rightauth=psk
    keyexchange=ikev1
    ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024
    ikelifetime=8h
    esp=aes128-sha1-modp1024
    lifetime=1h
    keyingtries=%forever
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    dpddelay=10s
    dpdtimeout=30s
    dpdaction=restart
    mark=100
$ cat /etc/strongswan/ipsec.secrets
52.y.y.y : PSK "<pre shared key of tunnel1>"
```

strongswan service is running and no errors

when I check the status I see

```
$strongswan status
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
     Tunnel1[1]: ESTABLISHED 23 minutes ago, 10.20.1.73[52.x.x.x]...52.y.y.y[52.y.y.y]
     Tunnel1{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: c9970cfa_i ce7ad76d_o
     Tunnel1{1}:   0.0.0.0/0 === 0.0.0.0/0
```

I did all these but I cannot ping the on-premise server from vpc server or the other-way round.
What else I need to do? Do I need to do any IP tables rules in strongswan instance

any help is really appreciated. Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks
Manoj

Explained above. the ping should be working

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a screenshot of your route tables, I cannot rule out a routing issue.
However, one thing which you did not mention to set and which by default is causing issues is EC2 feature "Source/Dest. Check". It has to be disabled on EC2 instances running StrongSwan.

Please see this post for more details including screenshots:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223611/4806599

Comment: Thanks for replying @GoodMirek. I actually did try disable the src/dest check on strongswan EC2. My route table details are below

Comment: **VPC1(this is the VPC1 main route table)***
0.0.0.0/0 igw-xxxx Active No
10.10.0.0/16 local Active No
10.20.0.0/16 vgw-xxx Active Yes
**VPC2(main route table)**
0.0.0.0/0 igw-xxxxx Active No
10.10.0.0/16 eni-xxxx   Active No
10.20.0.0/16 local Active No
**Private subnet route table**
0.0.0.0/0 nat-xxxx Active No
10.10.0.0/16 eni-xxx  Active No
10.20.0.0/16 local Active No
Here eni means network interface of the strongswan EC2

Comment: What I am not sure about is, how does the traffic in the VPC2 private subnet instance is routing through the strongswan EC2(which is in public subnet) without any routing or IP tables inside the strongswan EC2? Does the VPC2 route table and private subnet route table in the AWS console enough?